# Converting from binary to decimal from 2D int array in Java and storing variablse

Tags: java, binary, int

I am trying to iterate through a 2D array of ints and change all of their values from binary form to decimal form and store those values. To be more clear: I have a bunch of different int values which are all technically in binary form but their values are stored as ints. For instance, I might have a variable int example1 = 10001110 -- where the chars form a binary number but it's still a primitive int. So again, I need to convert those values from binary to decimal form and store them as ints. To make your lives a bit easier/more straightforward: the array that currently contains the ints has 8 rows and 2 columns: all of whose entries are in binary int form.

Thanks guys.

Comment: So you have a 2d array of binary strings and you would like it converted to a 2d array of ints?

Comment: Basically, yes. But it's an array of ints so I'm guessing I'd have to make the elements into binary strings, convert it to dec and then store the values from there. I'm not sure how I would do that or if it's even the correct approach.

Comment: If its an array of ints, why do you need to convert them? Changing the base won't change the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate through your array of binary strings and convert them, then store that in a new array.

`Integer.parseInt(binaryString, 2);`

Comment: Can I pass the elements of the int array as the binaryString argument in this case? Also, what does the 2 do?

Comment: The 2 tells it what base the string is in.

Comment: Okay, I think I see how this works. Thanks, I'll let you know if I'm still having trouble.

Comment: The're integer TYPES but they're not in base 10. Like if you have int i = 100101011101111; It's technically in base 10 in the computers mind, right? What I want to do is map that int i (a binary int) into decimal form and store that variable.

Comment: Oh! well that explanation is much more clear. Well use the above method, but first make them strings using `Integer.toString(value)`

Answer (score 1):

To change binary form to decimal form you can use `Integer.parseInt(someStringInteger, 2)`. To make `someStringInteger` use `Integer.parseInt(someInt)`. For example

```
//1110 (bin) -> 14 (dec)
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(1110), 2));//out -> 14
```

Comment: Okay I'm not getting an error so I think this worked. Thanks man